# Full page cache is not working for HTML

Tags: magento2, cache, redis

Magento 2 is configured to use redis for full page caching, caching is working normally for images, as shown in the below response header:

```
Cache-Control: public
```

But it is not working for html pages:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your full page cache is not working is possibly because you have a block which is being output across those pages which has a cacheable tag on it.

```
cacheable="false"
```

By find and removing this tag from the block, should allow your full page cache to start to working.